# Need assistance on script - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Need some help on a script I am doing... what I want to accomplish is when you hover over any a class of 'test' the #socializethis div will show.  When you mouseout it will disappear.  I have accomplished that, however, I need it to stay focused while actually over #socializethis as well so the box does not disappear.

Second thing I wish to do and have no idea how to go about is determine the position of the a class 'test' so I can show the box right beside it, under it, etc.

Im going to try and use this for a social sharing script.

index.html

```
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Untitled 1</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="share.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="share.css" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body>
<div id="social">
<a class="test" href="#">share this</a>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

share.css

```
img {border: none;}
#socializethis{
 height:37px;
 width:260px;
 position:absolute;
 bottom:500px;
 right:900px;
 overflow:hidden;
 display:none;
 visibility:hidden;
 padding:3px 3px 3px 3px;
 /* CSS3 */
 -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
 -moz-border-radius: 10px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px #555;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px #555;
 box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px #555;
}

#socializethis a{
 float:left; 
 width:32px;
 margin:3px 3px 3px 3px; 
 padding:0; 
}

#socializethis span{ 
 float:left; 
 margin:3px 3px 3px 3px;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #FFF;
 color:#444;
 font-size:12px;
}
```

share.js

```
(function( $ ) {
  $(document).ready(function() { 

  var twit = 'http://twitter.com/home?status='+title+'%20'+url;
  var facebook = 'http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='+url
  var digg = 'http://digg.com/submit?phase=2&url='+url+'&amp;title='+title;
  var stumbleupon = 'http://stumbleupon.com/submit?url='+url+'&amp;title='+title;
  var buzz = 'http://www.google.com/reader/link?url='+url+'&amp;title='+title+'&amp;srcURL='+host;
  var delicious  = 'http://del.icio.us/post?url='+url+'&amp;title='+title;

  var tbar = '<div id="socializethis"><span>Share<br /><a href="#min" id="minimize" title="Minimize"><img src="images/minimize.png" /> </a></span><div id="sicons">';
  tbar += '<a href="'+twit+'" id="twit" title="Share on twitter"><img src="images/twitter.png"  alt="Share on Twitter" width="32" height="32" /></a>';
  tbar += '<a href="'+facebook+'" id="facebook" title="Share on Facebook"><img src="images/facebook.png"  alt="Share on facebook" width="32" height="32" /></a>';
  tbar += '<a href="'+digg+'" id="digg" title="Share on Digg"><img src="images/digg.png"  alt="Share on Digg" width="32" height="32" /></a>';
  tbar += '<a href="'+stumbleupon+'" id="stumbleupon" title="Share on Stumbleupon"><img src="images/stumbleupon.png"  alt="Share on Stumbleupon" width="32" height="32" /></a>';
  tbar += '<a href="'+delicious+'" id="delicious" title="Share on Del.icio.us"><img src="images/delicious.png"  alt="Share on Delicious" width="32" height="32" /></a>';
  tbar += '<a href="'+buzz+'" id="buzz" title="Share on Buzz"><img src="images/google-buzz.png"  alt="Share on Buzz" width="32" height="32" /></a>';
  tbar += '</div></div>';

  // Add the share tool bar.
  $('#social').append(tbar);
  $('#socializethis').css({opacity: 1}); 

  // hover
  $('a.test').bind('mouseover',function(){
  $('#socializethis').animate({opacity: 1}, 600);
  $('#socializethis').css({display:'inline', visibility: 'visible'});   
  });

  $('#socializethis').bind('mouseover',function(){
  $('#socializethis').animate({opacity: 1}, 600);
  $('#socializethis').css({display:'inline', visibility: 'visible'});   
  });

  //leave
  $('a.test').bind('mouseout',function(){
    $('#socializethis').animate({opacity: 0}, 600, function(){
        $('#socializethis').css({display:'none', visibility: 'hidden'});   
    });
  }, 600);

  });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your first question - use jQuery's mouseenter and mouseleave instead of mouseover and mouseout.  Mouseenter will allow children to trigger their parent's mouseenter event. The jQuery page http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/ has a good demo at the bottom showing the difference. Then put both test and socialize elements in a parent div, which while socialize is hidden, will look only like test. This way mouseleave will not be called unless the user leaves both elements.