# show div on hover and stay till mouseleave?

Tags: jquery, css, css-sprites

when hovering on ".socialIcons", i want the div ".socialIconsShow" to fade in, and when I move the mouse to hover over ".socialIconsShow" they fadeout. Is there a way to have the icons stay visible after leaving ".socialIcons"?

```
<div class="socialNetworks">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Configure</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="socialIcons"><a href="#">Follow</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
         <div class="socialIconsShow">
          <div class="facebook"></div>
          <div class="twitter"></div>
          <div class="linkedin"></div>
        </div>
       </div>
```

Here's the link for you see what's going on:
http://www.imsmfg.com/new/test/index.php

Comment: why dont you `use .mouseleave` and `.mouseenter()`

Comment: Here's what i have to make it work currently:

$(".socialIcons").mouseenter(function(){
 $(".socialIconsShow").fadeIn('slow')  
}).mouseleave(function(){
 $(".socialIconsShow").fadeOut('slow');
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is exactly the same kind of thing I responded to yesterday:

[jQuery: Mousover on a div open submenu which should stay open when mouseout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7085758/jquery-mousover-on-a-div-open-submenu-which-should-stay-open-when-mouseout/7085858#7085858)

Comment: In the fiddle i provide in that answer, you should just change show() & hide() to fadeIn() & fadeOut() respectively.

Answer (score 1):

If you change your markup a little you should be sorted.

```
<div class="socialNetworks">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Configure</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="socialIcons">
            <a href="#">Follow</a>
            <!-- Jam these in here -->
            <div class="socialIconsShow">
                <div class="facebook"></div>
                <div class="twitter"></div>
                <div class="linkedin"></div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by re-structuring your markup and using the `:hover` selector like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Spycho/FJksb/).

This will not fade in / out. It will just show / hide.